# Email Outgoing Configuration - Failed to connect to the SMTP server

Tags: error, smtp

We are having trouble with setting up our SMTP server.

We have confirmed that the username, password, and port are correct but still get the following message:

[image]

Comment: How did you confirm that username, password, and port are correct? Are you able to send an email with another program from the same server? (For example using the smtp module in Drupal)

Comment: If possible, please also paste the text of the error into your question in addition to a screenshot?  This has several advantages - it makes it easier for folks answering to search on parts of the text, and makes it easier for folks with the same problem to find this solution via search engines.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error in red shows 'Name or service not known' so the problem is related to the server name 'smtp.touchingbase.org'.   There is no public DNS record for that.   Did you enter the wrong name?

Answer (score 1):

Hello all and thank you for the responses!

Ultimately we figured out that our SMTP server was, indeed, not correct.  We found the correct one by going into our Outlook email application and copying the correct SMTP server from there.

SUCCESS!

Thanks again!